# How to find the 999th shape in a pattern?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, pattern-recognition, word-problem

The pattern is of a triangle followed by 3 stars and 4 circles and it continues to repeat.

What will the 999th shape in the pattern be? Explain how you can tell.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** The $8$th, $16$th, and $24$th shapes will be the circle at the end of the cycle, and are each followed by a triangle.

Consider dividing by $8$. What do you remember about "remainders"?